# How to generate disposable channel invite link with telegram api?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I use [Telegram Api](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) .

I want to created invite link for channel.
I use this code .

```
 var botLink = (await botApi.CreateChatInviteLinkAsync(channelId, memberLimit: 1))
                                .InviteLink;
```

when i use this link for first time , it is ok and join the channel. when i click this link again, i get error `This link expire`.

but when i leave channel and click link , i can join the channel.
But I don't want to be able to use the link again.